# Track contributions on private repositories on Github

Tags: github, commit

I would like if we can show the trace of commits on Github of all of private repositories:

[image: Trace of github commits]

And of course, others users can't see details of your private commits, they just can see 'public' commits (+details) and 'private' commits (not details)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "traces of commits", you mean that you would like to track the contributions made to private repositories, [this help page](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/publicizing-or-hiding-your-private-contributions-on-your-profile) explains how.

To summarize, you can set (in your profile) that private activity (commits, pull requests, issues, etc.) will be visible in your contributions in an anonymized form.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks!